# How does Skilled Casting interact with Silent Spell and Still Spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spheres-of-power

A caster using the Spheres of Power system can get the drawback Skilled Casting. This forces her to roll a Craft, Perform, or Profession check in order to cast spells. This means that she must be able to perform the action, which is similar to having verbal or somatic casting components. The [description of the drawback](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/drawbacks/#List_of_General_Drawbacks) says:

> A caster with Skilled Casting must be able to perform their skill to use their magic, which is similar to but not the same as possessing other drawbacks. For example, a caster who must draw to create magic must have at least one hand free, although unless he also possesses Somatic Casting he may do so while wearing heavy armor without a chance of arcane spell failure.

How would metamagic feats such as Silent Spell and Still spell interact with said requirement?

For example, Thiana the Sorceress has Skilled Casting and Somatic Casting as drawbacks. Her Skilled Casting requires her to roll a Craft (calligraphy) check in order to cast a spell, so she needs a free hand to cast. She also chooses Still Spell as her first-level feat. I can imagine three ways in which the rules might interact:

1. Still Spell would be useless in most cases. She might be able to use it to ignore any chance of arcane spell failure, but she wouldn't be able to cast while being bound or otherwise immobilised, because she still needs a free hand to perform the skill check.
2. Still Spell would allow her to ignore both drawbacks. If she uses Still Spell when creating a magic effect, she doesn't need to move at all and therefore she doesn't need to do any skill checks either.
3. Still Spell would allow her to cast while being bound or otherwise immobilised, but would still require the skill check. So she wouldn't need to have at least one free hand to perform the skill check, but the skill check would still be necessary.

Which one of these is correct? Or do they interact in another way?

Comment: I think part of it might depend on the skill thats connected to the casting.  For instance perform singing shouldnt matter if you are bound, but perform dance should really.

Comment: I've removed the "skilled-casting" tag because it has no other questions at present. Feel free to rollback my edit if you think it is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Still Spell and Silent Spell have no affect on Skilled Casting requirements.

Still Spell specifically affects Somatic Casting. Silent Spell specifically affects Verbal Casting. Skilled Casting is neither of these and specifically does not have the drawbacks of the others;

> For example, a caster who must draw to create magic must have at least one hand free, although unless he also possesses Somatic Casting he **may do so while wearing heavy armor without a chance of arcane spell failure**. Likewise, a caster who uses music to create magic must be able to speak, but unless he also possesses Verbal Casting he **can do so quietly and not break stealth**.

Skilled Casting is created specifically to *not* be verbal or somatic components, and cannot be removed by abilities that relate to verbal or somatic.

### There could be a Metamagic for that.

If this is important to you, ask your GM if the two of you can homebrew a Metamagic that allows you to bypass the Skill check; perhaps it lets you perform it out of combat or ignore it for the spell, but it would probably cost 1 spell points, based on Still and Silent Spell.

Comment: Good idea about creating a new MM to deal with this. That balanced with the normal spell casting for still, silent, and eschew. Only noticeable difference is that normal casters still require focuses and expensive components, which is thankfully something PoW lacks.

Comment: I agree it ends up a little weird, but SoP didn't remove Silent or Still (or significantly modify them) so I guess that was already accounted for (or not, as the SoP designers decided).

Comment: I feel that this is probably the best RAW reading. However, that makes me feel that it needs some sort of extra ruling for Still/Silent Spell to be worth taking in the proposed scenario. Maybe I'll allow casters to spend 2 SP instead of one to forgo the requirements of both drawbacks.

Comment: I don't feel like that's necessary, but if it's your game then it's your choice. The restrictions of Skilled Casting are known and characters can be built to accommodate them without needing an entire feat and spending spell points constantly.